# Django background executor

Tags: python, django, executor

I am trying to run multiple tasks in queue. The tasks come on user input. What i tried was creating a singleton class with ThreadPoolExecutor property and adding tasks into it. The tasks are added fine, but it looks like only the first addition of set of tasks works. The following are added but not executed.

```
class WebsiteTagScrapper:
   class __WebsiteTagScrapper:
       def __init__(self):
           self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
   instance = None

   def __new__(cls):  # __new__ always a classmethod
       if not WebsiteTagScrapper.instance:
           WebsiteTagScrapper.instance = WebsiteTagScrapper.__WebsiteTagScrapper()
       return WebsiteTagScrapper.instance
```

Comment: you could perhaps post a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? or _at least_ how this thing is actually used in your code ?

Comment: Also, note that Django is more often than not served using multiprocessing, and even sometimes on multiple servers behind a load balancer, so your "singleton" will only be "single" for a given process of a given server. It won't be shared amongst processes and servers obviously...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers oh wow, good to know. I call this class in my api and pass the input url from POST as an argument

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i've seen people suggest using celery, but i thought that was an overkill

Comment: celery may or not be overkill for your use case - can't tell - but there are reasons why it's the most often suggested solution: properly handling distributed async tasks queues is not trivial. But you can consider some simpler / more lightweight solutions, cf https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

I used multiprocess in one of my project without using celery, cause i think it was overkill for my use. 
Maybe you could do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyQueuProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyQueuProcess, self).__init__()
        self.tasks = []


    def add_task(self, task):
        self.tasks.append(task)


    def run(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            #Do your task
```

You just have to create an instance in your view, set up your task and then `run()`. Also if you need to access your database, you will need to `import django` in your child and then make a `django.setup()`.